# Display radio box value using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have the HTML and JQuery code as below:

```
<form  action="" method="post" id="myform">
  <table border="0" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="7"><div class="title">CONNAISSANCE ET EXPERIENCE (O/E/AM/Cadres)</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul type="circle">
          <li>1. Des techniques et pratiques du métier</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input  type="radio" class="validate[required] radio" name="number1" id="number1" value="1"></td>
      <td><input name="number1" class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" id="number1" value="2"></td>
      <td><input name="number1" class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" id="number1" value="3"></td>
      <td><input name="number1" class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" id="number1" value="4"></td>
      <td><input name="number1" class="validate[required] radio" type="radio"  id="number1" value="5"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul type="circle">
          <li>2. Capacité d’apprentissage et d’adaptation</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" name="number2" value="1"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number2" type="radio" value="2"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number2" type="radio" value="3"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number2" type="radio" value="4"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number2" type="radio" value="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><ul type="circle">
          <li>3. Productivité/Rendement</li>
        </ul></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" name="number3" value="1"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number3" type="radio" value="2"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number3" type="radio" value="3"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number3" type="radio" value="4"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number3" type="radio" value="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><ul type="circle">
          <li>4. Polyvalenc</li>
        </ul></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" type="radio" name="number4" value="1"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number4" type="radio" value="2"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number4" type="radio" value="3"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number4" type="radio" value="4"></td>
      <td><input class="validate[required] radio" name="number4" type="radio" value="5"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="7">
          <script>
                 $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#test").click(function(){
                        var number1 = $('input[name=number1]:checked', '#myform').val();
                        var number2 = $('input[name=number2]:checked', '#myform').val();
                        var number3 = $('input[name=number3]:checked', '#myform').val();
                        var number4 = $('input[name=number4]:checked', '#myform').val();
                        var t1 = parseInt(number1);
                        var t2 = parseInt(number2);
                        var t3 = parseInt(number3);
                        var t4 = parseInt(number4);
                        var total = t1+t2+t3+t4;
                        alert (total);
                });
            });
          </script>

      <button name="btn" id="test">test</button>

      </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<form>
```

**I need:**
When I click on each radio box then I click on button submit it will be sum all values of radio box and display it.

**Problem**
I can only alert the sum value but I can not display it as normal.Example: PHP code when I want to display value I always use `echo` but for the JQuery I have never known it yet.So anyone help me please.And give me some idea,should I use JQuery like this or PHP that is better than for in this case. Thanks.

Comment: To which element _total_ should be appended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display rezult of form at current page you can use `'append'`, `'appendTo'`, `'html'`, `'text'`

1. http://api.jquery.com/append/
2. http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/
3. http://api.jquery.com/html/
4. http://api.jquery.com/text/ // **NOTE: in this case html will be added as plane text**

in order to find checked values you can use this script.

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#test').on('click',function(){
                    var $rez = $(".result");
                    $rez.html('')

                    $('#myform').find('input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
                        if($(this).attr('checked')=='checked')
                        {
                            $rez.append("class:"+$(this).attr('class'))
                            $rez.append("|name:"+$(this).attr('name'))
                            $rez.append("|value:"+$(this).attr('value'))

                                $rez.append("</br>")
                        }

                    });

                    return false;
             });
        });​
```

DEMO: ***[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74rSh/)***

Answer (score 0):

use like this for displaying data

```
$('#id_to_display').html(total);
```

this will help you out...

Answer (score 0):

it works for you...

```
 $("<div/>").html(total).appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add below line after or befor alert in jQuery.**

```
$('#mytotal').html(total);
```

**And Add below line befor test button.**

```
<div id="mytotal"></div>
```

then try it and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of alert() you can use a hidden field and push the value to that then on click of button you will get that in php page.

put this in your html section inside form

```
<input type="hidden" name="hid_total" id="hid_total" />
```

then instead of alert() use the below code.

```
jQuery("hid_total").val(total);
```

If you need to display the value in html you can choose text type instead of hidden